# Codeigniter: Config file making application behave wired in live and local

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm running into a strange trouble, i'm using 2.1 version of Codeigniter and the problem is when there is space after first line in config.php file
right after this code

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

Long story short my "add to cart" button doesn't work if there is space after that however i tried to set the default time in CI by doing

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
```

It works fine on local server but changed didn't get effected on Live server, Also even after removing space and default timezone the live version is behaving wired it doesn't add product to card.
here is the live server version you may check going to
 
"**online cart**" option select
"**Burgers**" option select
"**Add to cart**" and it will redirect to the "**view product**" page i don't get how's its happening.

Here is link: 193.42.156.121/hk 
The piece of code for two links on view:

slug)?>" class="view">
            View
            More

```
 <li> 
   <a href="<?php echo site_url().'cart/fetch_product/'.$product->id; ?>" class="view">
      Add to
      <br>
      Cart
    </a> 
</li>
```

The controller looks likes this where view send its link:

```
    function add_to_cart($data='')
{

        $product_id     = $this->input->post('id');
        $quantity       = $this->input->post('quantity');
        $post_options   = $this->input->post('option');

        if (!empty($data)) 
        {   
            $product_id     = $data['direct_product']->id;
            $quantity       = 1;
            // print_r($data['product']);
             // $data['product']->track_stock = $data['product']->track_stock = 0;
            // echo $stock =$data['product']->track_stock ;
        }
        // Get a cart-ready product array
        $product = $this->Product_model->get_cart_ready_product($product_id, $quantity);
        // print_r($product);
        // die();
        //if out of stock purchase is disabled, check to make sure there is inventory to support the cart.
        // echo $this->config->item('allow_os_purchase')." Purcahse allow <br>";
        // echo (bool)$product['track_stock'].' Track stock <br>';
        // die();
        if(!$this->config->item('allow_os_purchase') && (bool)$product['track_stock'])
        {
            $stock  = $this->Product_model->get_product($product_id);

            //loop through the products in the cart and make sure we don't have this in there already. If we do get those quantities as well
            $items      = $this->go_cart->contents();
            $qty_count  = $quantity;
            foreach($items as $item)
            {
                if(intval($item['id']) == intval($product_id))
                {
                    $qty_count = $qty_count + $item['quantity'];
                }
                echo $qty_count."<br>";
            }

            if($stock->quantity < $qty_count)
            {
                //we don't have this much in stock
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', sprintf(lang('not_enough_stock'), $stock->name, $stock->quantity));
                $this->session->set_flashdata('quantity', $quantity);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('option_values', $post_options);


                redirect($this->Product_model->get_slug($product_id));
            }
        }
        // echo $this->config->item('allow_os_purchase')." Purcahse allow <br>";
        // echo (bool)$product['track_stock'].' Track stock <br>';
        // die();

        // Validate Options 
        // this returns a status array, with product item array automatically modified and options added
        //  Warning: this method receives the product by reference
        $status = $this->Option_model->validate_product_options($product, $post_options);
        // print_r($status);
        // die();

        $start_time_in_24_hour  = date("H:i", strtotime($this->setting['opening_time']));
        $end_time_in_24_hour    = date("H:i", strtotime($this->setting['closing_time']));
        $timestamp = date("H:i", time());
        if(
            !($start_time_in_24_hour <= $timestamp && $end_time_in_24_hour <= $timestamp)
          )
        {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'shop is closed');
            redirect($this->Product_model->get_slug($product_id));
        }

        if( ! $status['validated'])
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('quantity', $quantity);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $status['message']);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('option_values', $post_options);

            redirect($this->Product_model->get_slug($product_id));

        } 
        else 
        {
            //Add the original option vars to the array so we can edit it later
            $product['post_options']    = $post_options;

            //is giftcard
            $product['is_gc']           = false;

            // Add the product item to the cart, also updates coupon discounts automatically
            // print_r($product);
            // die();
            $this->go_cart->insert($product);

            if (!empty($data)) 
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Product added');
                redirect('onlineOrder');
            }
            // go go gadget cart!
            redirect('cart/view_cart');
        }
    // }
}
```

each value i get in this function is right but don't know hy my link
http://193.42.156.121/hk/cart/fetch_product/56
gets redirected to 
http://193.42.156.121/hk/veggie-burger
how is it doing that ? Any idea ?

Comment: Juts a note you need to set your base url in config.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here i was redirecting to wrong link, stupid me

```
 if(!($start_time_in_24_hour <= $timestamp && $end_time_in_24_hour <= $timestamp))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'shop is closed');
        redirect($this->Product_model->get_slug($product_id));
    }
```

it should be like:

```
 if(!($start_time_in_24_hour <= $timestamp && $end_time_in_24_hour <= $timestamp) )
    {

        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'shop is closed');
        redirect('onlineOrders');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
if(! ini_get('date.timezone')){
    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
}
```

In this way, it will not change any other thing in config.php file

Comment: Doesn't work :( plus do you have any idea why its redirecting to the product's url ?

Comment: Well, need to check the live url, if you have.